# input number mask - prevent minus sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking

Trying to build an own input number mask for number with space as separator and no decimals. Both positive and negative numbers allowed. Solution below so far. One issue, how to not allow only a minus sign (input field should then be empty or 0) and trailing minus signs? Any other suggestions how to improve code?

```js
function thousandany(x) {
  return x
    .replace(/(?!-)\D+/g, '') //ta bort alla utom nummer
    .toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val(thousandany($(this).val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="text-align:right">
```

Comment: not sure how you would prevent it, you can run validation after and so something since it requires 2 keystrokes to know if it would be valid. And you code needs to handle paste.

Comment: @epascarello It does handle paste as far as I see. I pasted "asdf" and it removed the whole string.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde let me guess, you use Ctrl + V?

Comment: @epascarello yea that was it. What was the problem with that? is it not the same?

Comment: There are multiple ways to paste without using the key press event.

Comment: the regex for a single `-` sign is `/^-$/`

Comment: How are you supposed to be able to type a negative number if you're not allowed to type a minus sign? If you try to validate on keyup then whenever you start typing a negative number it will immediately be reset to 0 or empty. Unless you mean that the minus sign is supposed to come at the end?

Comment: @KevinLindmark why do you want to do this? It's a bad idea.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain yea I think he mens at the end

Comment: @AJcodez - well the the input value is to be used in the creation of a pdf report and the field should be a number and I just want to minimise the risk a user forgets he/she entered a single "-".

Comment: @KevinLindmark the problem with input masks in my experience is that users think it's broken when they type something and it doesn't print as expected. So the user press it again and get confused. I would avoid input masks unless to format as it appears on a credit card, etc. Usually you want to wait until they are done typing, then give the field a red border and red error message explaining the format, and disable the submit button for the form. For small screens see if there is a input type or setting that shows a keyboard that encourages typing legal characters.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know much about regex, but your UX does not seem very user-friendly and confortable. Why not run further validation on the data to see if it works fine? You are forcing the user to type only on the right side. **If you want to change the text you have inputted, and it has 20 figures, you would have to remove all of them just to change the first one.**

I would recommend, as an alternative approach, as I said, to run validation to the code **after the user has finished typing the data** (so it does not become annoying), or for example when it focuses out of the input. The user is not idiot, if you tell him once that he has to enter, say, positive numbers, say, an integer, he will change the input accordingly. To be constantly tricking his or her input can actually become annoying, especially if you cannot change the text you have already written.

You can check whether it is a valid number, whether it is integer, whether it is positive, etc. It makes much more sense for me than to be forcing the input in such a way, and it also makes the code much more complicated – when my opinion is that it is unnecessary.

Also do not forget that there are other aspects such as scientific notation (which you might want to consider) which use also letters and would require a much more complex regex if you wanted to implement them at all.

Of course I know this does not directly answer your question, but it might make you re-think if the effort you are making is completely necessary or you can follow a more efficient approach.

An example of how you could do it after the user focuses out or clicks a specific button, would be:

```
$(document).ready(startCheck)

function startCheck() {

    $("#myInputField").focusout(checkData)
    %("#myButton").click(checkData)
}

function checkData() {
    var data = $("#myInputField").val();
    if $.isNumeric(data) {
        // do something
    } else {
        alert("Please input a number")
}
```

Of course you can change it on your convenience, to do a more user-friendly way of notifying that input is incorrect, and to adjust whether you want only integers to pass, or positive values to pass, etc.